# ext js multiple instances of same grid

Tags: extjs, model, grid, store

I'm having an issue with multiple instances of an ext js grid all showing the same data.  I  am using Ext js 4.1.1.

I have a main tab panel.  In that panel, there are multiple people tabs.  Inside each person tab is a details tab and a family tab.

The details tab is a simple form with text boxes, combo boxes, etc.  The family tab has both a dataview and a grid.

If only one person tab is open at a time, everything works fine.  As soon as a second person is opened, the family tabs look the same (both the dataview and the grid).  It seems to me that the problem has something to do with the model.  Perhaps they are sharing the same instance of the model, and that is causing one refresh to change all the data.  The dataview and the grid both have the same problem, but I think that if I can fix the problem with the grid, then I can apply the same logic to fix the dataview.  I will leave the code for the dataview out of this question unless it becomes relevant.

PersonTab.js

```
Ext.require('Client.view.MainTab.PersonDetailsForm');
Ext.require('Client.view.MainTab.PersonFamilyForm');
Ext.require('Client.view.MainTab.EventForm');

Ext.define('Client.view.MainTab.PersonTab',
{
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    waitMsgTarget: true,
    alias: 'widget.MainTabPersonTab',
    layout: 'fit',
    activeTab: 0,
    tabPosition: 'bottom',
    items:
        [
            {
                title: 'Details',
                closable: false,
                xtype: 'MainTabPersonDetailsForm'
            },
            {
                title: 'Family',
                closable: false,
                xtype: 'MainTabPersonFamilyForm'
            },
            {
                title: 'page 3',
                closable: false,
                xtype: 'MainTabEventForm'
            }
        ]
});
```

MainTabPersonFamilyForm.js

```
Ext.require('Client.view.MainTab.PersonFamilyHeadOfHouseholdDataView');
Ext.require('Client.view.MainTab.PersonFamilyGrid');

Ext.define('Client.view.MainTab.PersonFamilyForm',
{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.MainTabPersonFamilyForm',
    waitMsgTarget: true,
    padding: '5 0 0 0',
    autoScroll: true,
    items:
        [
            {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                name: 'HeadOfHouseholdLabel',
                value: 'The head of my household is:'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'MainTabPersonFamilyHeadOfHouseholdDataView'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                boxLabel: "Use my Head of Household's address as my address",
                boxLabelAlign: 'after',
                inputValue: true,
                name: 'UseHeadOfHouseholdAddress',
                allowBlank: true,
                padding: '0 20 5 0'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'MainTabPersonFamilyGrid'
            }
        ],
    config:
        {
            idPerson: ''
        }
});
```

MainTabPersonFamilyGrid.js

```
Ext.require('Client.store.PersonFamilyGrid');
Ext.require('Ext.ux.CheckColumn');

Ext.define('Client.view.MainTab.PersonFamilyGrid',
{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.MainTabPersonFamilyGrid',
    waitMsgTarget: true,
    padding: '5 0 0 0',
    xtype: 'grid',
    title: 'My Family Members',
    store: Ext.create('Client.store.PersonFamilyGrid'),
    plugins: Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing'),
    viewConfig:
        {
            plugins:
                {
                    ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                    dragGroup: 'PersonFamilyGridTrash'
                }
        },
    columns:
        [
            { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'},
            { text: 'Relationship', dataIndex: 'Relationship', editor: { xtype: 'combobox', allowblank: true, displayField: 'display', valueField: 'value', editable: false, store: Ext.create('Client.store.Gender') }},
            { xtype: 'checkcolumn', text: 'Is My Guardian', dataIndex: 'IsMyGuardian', editor: { xtype: 'checkboxfield', allowBlank: true, inputValue: true }},
            { xtype: 'checkcolumn', text: 'I Am Guardian', dataIndex: 'IAmGuardian', editor: { xtype: 'checkboxfield', allowBlank: true, inputValue: true } }
        ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    buttons:
        [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                cls: 'trash-btn',
                iconCls: 'trash-icon-large',
                width: 64,
                height: 64,
                action: 'trash'
            }
        ]
});
```

PersonFamilyGrid.js (store)

```
Ext.require('Client.model.PersonFamilyGrid');

Ext.define('Client.store.PersonFamilyGrid',
{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: false,
    model: 'Client.model.PersonFamilyGrid',
    proxy:
        {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/Person/GetFamily',
            reader:
                {
                    type: 'json'
                }
        }
});
```

PersonFamilyGrid.js (model)

```
Ext.define('Client.model.PersonFamilyGrid',
{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:
        [
            'idFamily',
            'idPerson',
            'idFamilyMember',
            'Name',
            'Relationship',
            'IsMyGuardian',
            'IAmGuardian'
        ]
});
```

relevant code from the controller:

```
....
....
var personTab = thisController.getMainTabPanel().add({
     xtype: 'MainTabPersonTab',
     title: dropData.data['Title'],
     closable: true,
     layout: 'fit',
     tabpanelid: dropData.data['ID'],
     tabpaneltype: dropData.data['Type']
});

personTab.items.items[0].idPerson = dropData.data['ID'];
personTab.items.items[1].idPerson = dropData.data['ID'];

thisController.getMainTabPanel().setActiveTab(personTab);
....
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the `store` as a property on your grid prototype and creating it once at class definition time. That means that all your grids instantiated from that class will share the exact same store.

Note that you're also creating a single `cellediting` plugin that will be shared with all instantiations of that grid as well. That definitely won't work. You likely will only be able to edit in either the first or last grid that was instantiated.

In general you should not be setting properties like `store`, `plugins`, `viewConfig` or `columns` on the class prototype. Instead you should override `initComponent` and set them inside that method so that each instantiation of your grid gets a unique copy of those properties.

```
Ext.define('Client.view.MainTab.PersonFamilyGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.MainTabPersonFamilyGrid',
    waitMsgTarget: true,
    padding: '5 0 0 0',
    title: 'My Family Members',
    height: 200,
    width: 400

    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            // Each grid will create its own store now when it is initialized.
            store: Ext.create('Client.store.PersonFamilyGrid'),
            // you may need to add the plugin in the config for this
            // grid
            plugins: Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing'),
            viewConfig: {
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                    dragGroup: 'PersonFamilyGridTrash'
                }
            },
            columns: /* ... */
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great. Would initComponent() usually go in the view definition? I thought it should go in the controller. I tried putting it in the controller and loading the grid data in the render event, but the data would not show up. Putting the initComponent() in the view works, though.

Comment: `initComponent` is a method belonging to `Ext.Component` and all its subclasses. `Ext.app.Controller` is not a component. `initComponent` is called by the constructor when the component is being initialized. You can set these properties in the config object that is passed to the constructor instead of configuring everything at class definition time. Most of the time there is no need to extend the Grid and create your own, you can just create a normal grid and pass in the configs you need (store, columns, plugins, etc) to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly, but from the code you have submitted it appears that you are not setting the `id` parameter on your tabs and your stores, which causes DOM collisions as the `id` is used to make a component globally unique. This has caused me grief in the past when sub-classing components (such as tabs and stores) and using multiple instances of those classes.

Try giving each one a unique identifier (such as the person id) and then referencing them using that id:

```
var personTab = thisController.getMainTabPanel().add({
    id: 'cmp-person-id',
    xtype: 'MainTabPersonTab',
    ...

store: Ext.create('Client.store.PersonFamilyGrid',
{
    id: 'store-person-id',
    ...
});

Ext.getCmp('cmp-person-id');

Ext.StoreManager.lookup('store-person-id');
```

Hope that helps.